# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty

I am using aspectJ in my project and added dependencies in my POM file. When i am running my application on Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile, in the library folder aspectj.jar is not getting added/created. I am very new to using spring and never used server's to run a application. When i am trying to run the application on the server i am getting the following exception:

Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException`

Can anyone please team whats going on wrong with the application ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure that aspectj is available to your application at runtime. The two basic approaches for this are to package it up with your application zip, or to make it available as a shared library in the server. The first approach has the advantage that you don't need to do any extra config, and no matter where you run your application, the dependency will be there. However, it has the disadvantage of bloating your application. If you end up running multiple applications on the server, it could also cause the apps to use more memory than they would if they were just using a shared copy.

For the first approach, if your dependency has the default scope in the pom, maven should automatically copy it to WEB-INF/lib (assuming your application is a war).

For the second approach, you can configure it in Liberty as a [global library](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html) (available to all applications) by copying it to a wlp/usr/shared/config/lib/global folder in your Liberty install.